# Does the ATF have jurisdiction to prohibit gun sales to marijuana users when the marijuana used is not subject to federal jurisdiction?

Tags: jurisdiction, us-federal-government, medical-marijuana

Does the ATF have jurisdiction to prohibit gun sales to marijuana users when the marijuana used is not subject to federal jurisdiction?

https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/commerce_clause

If the marijuana used was grown locally and did not travel in interstate commerce it would seem that the use of marijuana in states where this use is legal could not be construed as illegal under federal law because the federal government lacks jurisdiction under the commerce clause.

## Apparently smoking marijuana takes away your 2nd amendment rights:

https://www.atf.gov/firearms/docs/open-letter/all-ffls-sept2011-open-letter-marijuana-medicinal-purposes/download

Comment: AFAIK, courts have not agreed with that argument: even when a product is produced and consumed within a single state, they've held it can still "affect" interstate commerce, and therefore the federal government may have the power to regulate it.   A famous example is [*Wickard v. Filburn*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wickard_v._Filburn) where SCOTUS ruled the federal government could penalize a wheat farmer for growing more wheat than his quota, even though he fed it to his own animals.

Comment: *Gonzales v. Raich*, discussed on the page you linked, also seems relevant as it specifically held that a federal marijuana ban applied to the product produced and used within a state.

Comment: @NateEldredge The Court decided that Filburn's wheat-growing activities reduced the amount of wheat he would buy for animal feed on the open market, which is traded nationally, is thus interstate, and is therefore within the scope of the Commerce Clause. Thus seemingly not applicable.

Comment: @NateEldredge "Producing marijuana only for home consumption, moreover, was similar to the farmer's production of wheat in the Wickard case because it had an effect on the national market for the drug. As in that case, then, it could be regulated by the federal government under the Commerce Clause." In the Wickard case federal subsidies were directly involved in regulating the market for wheat for the purpose of regulating the price of wheat. Wickard's actions interfered with this purpose. The second case has no such interference of purpose.

Comment: @polcott You might disagree with the court's holding in *Gonzales v. Raich*, but it's still the law of the land.

Comment: @NateEldredge So it looks like simply using locally grown marijuana has not been decided to fall under federal jurisdiction and seemingly cannot be so decided, otherwise this would create a slippery slope causing most everything to fall under federal jurisdiction. Because of this it looks like the ATF would not have the authority to prohibit gun sales because the marijuana use would not be illegal under federal law because this use is outside of the scope of federal jurisdiction.

Comment: @polcott Marijuana being illegal on the federal level did not stop a national market for it developing, even long before any states even started to think about legalizing it for medicinal or recreational purposes.  Just because trading in something is illegal doesn't stop people from trading in it.  If it did, the war on drugs would have ended quickly and easily, and mobsters and the mafia would be a rapidly aging trope no one can directly relate to anymore. As such Congress can still regulate national markets in illegal goods.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Regulating a national market where the states agree that something should be illegal is OK. Superseding and overriding the will of the states and the people n the states is not OK. In the two cases cited neither one of them overrode the will of the states or the will of the people in the states.

Comment: Note that the regulation "no gun sales to marijuana users" doesn't necessarily hinge on the question of whether marijuana use is legal or not.  As a different example, consuming alcohol is perfectly legal, but could the ATF have a regulation "no gun sales to alcoholics"?  I suspect the answer is yes, and that it flows from their power to regulate gun sales in general, rather than anything about alcohol in particular.  So you may be getting hung up on a point that isn't actually relevant.

Comment: @NateEldredge The most disturbing part continues to be that the feds are circumventing the will of the democracy. The people have decided that the use of marijuana is not illegal in some states and the feds are superseding and overriding the will of the people in these states.

Comment: Well, I am not going to enter into a debate on that.  I am speaking only of the law as it has been interpreted by courts.  Discussions of how we think the law ought to work, or whether various court decisions are right or wrong, are off-topic for this site.

Comment: @NateEldredge I was thinking that a literal interpretation of the commerce clause must take these things into account. The whole purpose of the commerce clause is to prevent this kind of judicial over-reach, thus a subsequent case might reverse this decision on this basis.

Comment: @polcott - Federal laws are made democratically, just as state and local laws. It is clear from the supremacy clause of the constitution that a federal law beats state law even though you wish it were not true.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite "Federal laws are made democratically" Not in the case of marijuana: https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2019/11/14/americans-support-marijuana-legalization/  (I would have provided the Gallup pool, but their site was down).

Comment: @polcott - we have a representative form of democracy in the U.S. The people we vote into office make the laws. Laws are not made by direct vote of the electorate.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite  Democracy (Greek: δημοκρατία, The term is derived from the Greek words dēmokratiā, dēmos (“people”) and kratos (“rule”) "rule by [the] people") 

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supermajority

2/3 of the people want marijuana legalized and the term: Democracy  most literally means "rule by [the] people" therefore the feds need to submit to the will of the people. We are gradually sliding towards totalitarianism.

Comment: Law makers everywhere should pay more attention to the people. Like the 60% of people who would like stricter gun laws. The founders rejected direct "rule by the people". They thought it would be too chaotic and we would be ruled by a mob mentality. Thus the House and the, even purposely slower, Senate.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Ballot initiatives work fine in the states. The feds are influenced far too much by organizations that don't have the best interests of the people in mind.

Comment: I agree that lobbyist and money are a problem.

Comment: The constitution explicitly states that federal law trumps state and local laws wherever they might come into conflict.  So this is in fact not disrupting the will of the people (or, more accurately, the will of a voting majority of people in a minority of states), it is in fact a foundational feature of that will.  But, again, this is not a site for discussing what the law *should* be in one's opinion, but rather what the law *is* as a matter of fact.  Try using chat if you want to have such a discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Supreme Court has ruled, in [Gonzales v. Raich](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supct/html/03-1454.ZS.html), 545 U.S. 1, that Congress is empowered to pass the Controlled Substances Act: whether or not you agree with the ruling, that is what the current law is. Citing [Wickard v. Filburn](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/317/111), 317 U.S. 111 and [Perez v. US](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/402/146), 402 U.S. 146, the court held that

> If Congress decides that the “‘total incidence’” of a practice poses a
>   threat to a national market, it may regulate the entire class

because Congress may conclude that

> failure to regulate that class of activity would undercut the
>   regulation of the interstate market in that commodity

Then comparing Raich (a medical marijuana case) and Wickard, the court held that

> In both cases, the regulation is squarely within Congress’ commerce
>   power because production of the commodity meant for home consumption,
>   be it wheat or marijuana, has a substantial effect on supply and
>   demand in the national market for that commodity.

and

> the Court has no difficulty concluding that Congress had a rational
>   basis for believing that failure to regulate the intrastate
>   manufacture and possession of marijuana would leave a gaping hole in
>   the CSA

While there are various differences between Wickard and Raich, the court gets to decide which similarities are most important and which differences should be set aside. The disagreement is not trivial: O'connor, Rehnquist and Thomas dissented, finding that the Commerce clause is there to

> protect historic spheres of state sovereignty from excessive federal
>   encroachment and thereby to maintain the distribution of power
>   fundamental to our federalist system of government

But it was a minority view that the states should have to power to set in-state rules for commerce.

Comment: "production of the commodity meant for home consumption, be it wheat or marijuana, has a substantial effect on supply and demand in the national market for that commodity." Wait a minute here, what about mere consumption of that commodity? The above case would rule that the growers can't own guns. It doesn't seem to apply to the consumers.

Comment: Guns are covered by the Second Amendment.

Comment: Apparently smoking marijuana takes away your 2nd amendment rights: https://www.atf.gov/firearms/docs/open-letter/all-ffls-sept2011-open-letter-marijuana-medicinal-purposes/download

Comment: Yes, that is true of various felonies.

Comment: The supreme court ruling that you seemed to so carefully and clearly analyzed does not seem to apply to possession and use. It only applied to: "production of the commodity".

Comment: "the Court has no difficulty concluding that Congress had a rational basis for believing that failure to regulate the intrastate manufacture and possession of marijuana would leave a gaping hole in the CSA"  That they really hate the result of the commerce clause in no basis what-so-ever to ignore it. If they can't specifically show how the commerce clause does not apply then they lose.

Comment: I don't think that Gonzales v. Raich, applies to use and possession. It is incorrect reasoning to say that because the Fed can regulate all X's  that are Y's  that the fact that some X's are Y's lets them regulate all X's. X=drug-commerce, Y=interstate-commerce.

Comment: @polcott Your argument seems to be “the Supreme Court got it wrong.” It doesn’t matter if you think the Supreme Court got it wrong. Unless the Supreme Court decides they interpreted the Constitution wrong or the Constitution is amended, the Supreme Court’s interpretation is *by definition* the correct one. Any argument that they’re wrong is an argument about what the law should be, not an argument about what the law is.

Comment: @polcott If you’re arguing that possession of marijuana that never left the state isn’t within Congress’s power to regulate, you have to start from the premise that *Gonzales v. Raich* is correct. If your argument requires *Gonzales* to be wrong, you’re arguing for a change in the law. Absent a constitutional amendment, only the Supreme Court can change this law (Congress could repeal the CSA but couldn’t bar a future Congress from reenacting it).

Comment: @cpast I am not convinced that the scope of Gonzales v. Raich applies to possession and use because the decision of the scope of Gonzales v. Raich relative to the commerce clause only seemed to address the "production of the commodity" combined with the use of that commodity. It did not seem to directly address the use of that commodity separately. In Wickard v. Filburn, if the farmer fed someone else's grain to his cattle the ruling would seem to cease to apply. It only applied because he was trying to skirt the price support system.

Comment: @polcott Raich didn’t grow marijuana, she just possessed it (“use” isn’t a crime under the CSA, possession is the charge that applies to users). Raich and the other respondents sought an order prohibiting the DOJ from enforcing the CSA against them to the extent it forbade them from possessing, obtaining, *or* manufacturing marijuana. The Court held that both possession *and* production were within Congress’s regulatory power.

Comment: @ cpast "Raich didn’t grow marijuana, she just possessed it" That was sufficiently specific to indicate that the ruling does apply to possession.

Answer (score 5):

> If the marijuana used was grown locally and did not travel in interstate commerce it would seem that the use of marijuana in states where this use is legal could not be construed as illegal under federal law because the federal government lacks jurisdiction under the commerce clause.

You might think that, but you'd be wrong. In *Gonzales v. Raich* ([545 U.S. 1](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/545/1/)), the respondents were California residents who used locally-grown marijuana in ways that were legal under California law. One respondent actually grew the marijuana herself and only used it herself, never selling or distributing it to anyone. Nevertheless, the Supreme Court held that the federal Controlled Substances Act could constitutionally regulate the respondents' activities. The basic reasoning was that despite the illegality of the marijuana market, there still *is* a national marijuana market that personal growth of marijuana could affect. You might think this is a tenuous argument, and you wouldn't be the only one to feel that way, but it is the law of the land.

Comment: This seems to form a slippery slope where the federal government could take totalitarian control over anything involving commerce.

Comment: @polcott A concern many have raised (and going well beyond commerce), yes, but there are other relatively recent rulings on the commerce clause that actually pared down its otherwise very considerable power.  A federal law regarding guns near schools was struck down because the basis for invoking the commerce clause was too tenuous and distant.  However a subsequent modification to that law that made it apply to guns *that were transported between states* near schools has been upheld because it explicitly invokes and restrains itself to matters of interstate commerce.